# The next number in sequence

Tags: number-sequence

We have following sequence:

> 12345, 33552, 45624, 66345, 73557, 45678, 66885, 78957, 99678

What will be the next number?

Answer is known now (@JonMark Perry and @Mark found it). The answer is:

Danger! It is the correct answer:

> 106890

or

> A688A

but they found it by some properties of this sequence not by general rule and this general rule is very different (And it is interesting that this sequence has so many properties!).

Now the question is: what is the general rule?

**Hint 1**:

> notice that always two of five digits are the same (but in different place) like in the previous one number.

**Hint 2**:

> There are always the same two digits

**Hint 3**:

> For example 12**3**4**5** -> 3**3**5**5**2. Next 33**5**5**2** -> 4**5**6**2**4 and so on.

**Hint 4**:

> What with other digits?

**Hint 5**

> Because of general rule, the answer (10th number in sequence) is the first one that doesn't pass rule 99**6**7**8** -> 10**6**8**9**0 But it can be fixed if we choose A688A answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure, but:

> $A688A$, or $1068810$ if not using single digits

because:

> the sequence repeats every five, with (plus 3) mapped across all the digits. You can use the map from $66345 \to 73557$ to map from $99678$.

Also:

> the sum of digits divided by $3$ is $n+4$ for the $n^{th}$ term.

The general rule is:

> $abcde \to (b+1)c(d+1)e(a+1)$

Comment: It is not my answer but I think it is also correct (in my answer I do everything in base 10)

Comment: Yes, it is. Bravo :)

Comment: Nice one, gratz 

Answer (score 3):

The initial guess was that the answer is either:

> 106890, or 6880, or 6890, or 06880

Reasoning:

> Digits of numbers no. 6 through 9 are numbers 1-4 plus 3. (12345 +3 = 45678 etc.). The 5th number is 73557, but its unclear whether the author intended to treat it as a whole number or separate digits. Therefore, I suggested more than one answer.

After the hint from the author:

> The difference between numbers 1 and 2 is 33552-12345=21207, between 2 and 3: 45624-33552=12072, between 3 and 4: 66345-45624=20721. The difference shifts numbers, therefore the next one is 07212 (7212).
>  Checking it: 66345+7212=73557 (5th number). Continuing on, 73557+72120=145677; 6th number is 45678, so I guess the spare digit is added to the end. Moving on, 9th number is 99678 plus 7212 = 106890.

The final-final answer is:

> Well, back to the very start... **106890**.

P.S:

> But the "regular math" is broken on 6th number anyways, as far as I'm concerned. :)

P.P.S:

> Thanks @JonMark Perry for the edits. :)

Comment: Got the same solution, but you were too fast ;)

Comment: One of your answers is correct but reason is different. It is possible to guess 4th number when you have only three of them (for example: guess 66345 when you have 12345, 33552, 45624). Think about that and you will know why one of them is correct :)

Comment: I think I got it now. :)

Comment: Correct reasoning but you chose (created) wrong answer :)

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz, how about now? :)

Comment: Simpler is better ;) @JonMarkPerry No... difference is 07212 (=7212) like between 73557 and 66345. Now we have x - 99678 = 7212 and my only puzzle was to guess "x" with normal, math rules :) So the answer is not 6890.

Comment: if the last digit is added to the start, isn't the answer $06891$?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yeah, but Piotr told me that one of my initial guesses was correct, plus he insisted on normal math rules. Otherwise I would have guessed 06891 (6891), too.

Comment: The answer is correct now, but I should explain now why normal math is not broken. Both of you noticed some true properties of this sequence (about difference and about +3 for every five numbers) but it is created in different way and I didn't suppose it will have so many properties.

Comment: Should I edit my question to show how the sequence is created (what is the rule)? I am new so I don't know where to show it. Or maybe I should add clue/hint for that...

Comment: LOL that's even cooler. I'm new too, but I guess you can add a hint under a spoiler in the question.

Comment: Mark and @JonMarkPerry I added hints for general rule of sequence. Accepted answer will be the answer with correct explanation of general rule :)